# How to best tune a Windows development machine?

Tags: windows, performance, development, tuning

How to best tune a Windows PC for development purposes?

Answer (score 6):

- [Disable the NTFS Last Access Time Stamp](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/50/);
- [Turn off indexing and speed up Windows XP](http://lifehacker.com/software/optimization/turn-off-indexing-and-speed-up-windows-xp-031440.php); and
- [Turn off unnecessary services](http://www.jasonn.com/turning_off_unnecessary_services_on_windows_xp).

Answer (score 2):

Either don't install antivirus software or disable scan-on-access (and if not system-wide, then at least for your development directories). This can make a big difference in compile time.

See also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1217/what-antivirus-do-you-recommend-for-dev-boxes/1309#1309).

Comment: Also, most antivirus scanners have the ability to filter out certain directories from real-time scanning.

Answer (score 1):

There are some utilites to change the ntfs behavior, instead of editing the registry.

fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1

fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1

put a second disk in the machine, to avoid thrashing

Answer (score 0):

Set 1600x1200 or 1960x1200 or whatever is appropriate -- some very high resolution screen, but then set big fonts so you don't need a magnifying glass to read.  This allows you to have multiple windows up next to each other.